# Navigating from Detail to Master without a Navigation Property in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Given the following (simplified) classes:

```
public class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
}
```

How can I select a specific Detail instance given a UniqueName for the Master and a UniqueCode for the Detail using Linq to Entities?

Note that there is no navigation property from Detail to Master.

If there were a navigation property, I think I could do something like this:

```
Detail detail = (from m in ctx.Master.Include(p=>p.Details)
                 join d in ctx.Details
                 on m.Id = d.MasterId
                 where m.UniqueName == "Something" && d.UniqueCode == "Else"
                 select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

Without that navigation property from Detail to Master, I don't see how to proceed without first fetching the Master including all Detail instances of that Master, and then iterating the Detail instances.  That could be quite inefficient if there are many Detail instances for a given Master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var detail = ctx.Master.Where(m => m.UniqueName == "Something")
    .Select(m => m.Details.Where(d => d.UniqueCode == "Else").FirstOrDefault())
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Can that be represented as a query expression?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure that you use linq to objects, or linq to entities. If only your classes involved try this query:

```
    var mst = new List<Master> { 
        new Master { Id = 1, UniqueName = "Something", Details = new List<Detail> { 
            new Detail { Id = 10, UniqueCode = "Else" }, new Detail { Id = 11, UniqueCode = "det1" }} 
        } ,
        new Master { Id = 2, UniqueName = "mast2", Details = new List<Detail> { new Detail { Id = 20, UniqueCode = "det2" } } } 
    };

    var detail = (from d in
                        ((from m in mst
                            where m.UniqueName == "Something"
                            select m.Details).SingleOrDefault())
                where d.UniqueCode == "Else"
                select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you have datatables then Detail table probably has a MasterID (int) column, so I would try the following query:

```
    var detail = (from d in ctx.Detail
                    where d.MasterID == (
                        (from m in ctx.Master
                         where m.UniqueName == "Something"
                         select m.Id).SingleOrDefault())
                    && d.UniqueCode == "Else"
                    select d).SingleOrDefault();
```